# How to get Different Optional type of Object from CompletableFuture

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have one code snippet, which is calling 2 different services based on some a `if` condition. And both the services return `CompletableFuture<Optional<SomeObject>>`. Following is the code logic looks like

```
if(someCondition){
  CompletableFuture<Optional<SomeObjectType1>> = service1.call();
}else{
  CompletableFuture<Optional<SomeObjectType2>> = service2.call();
}
```

And both `SomeObjectType1` and `SomeObjectType2` have a `String` inside it, which is of my interest. My current code looks like this:

```
private ContentWrapper getContentWrapper(input1, input2, ....) {
    String content = null;
    if (some_condition is true) {
        List<Object_Type_1> list = service1.fetchTheCompletableFuture(..... inputs...)
                .join()
                .map(ListOutput::getList)
                .orElse(null);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list)) {
            content = list.get(0).getContent();
        }
    } else {
        content = service2
                .fetchTheCompletableFuture(..... inputs...)
                .join()
                .map(RenderedContent::getContent)
                .orElse(null);
    }
    return content != null ? new ContentWrapper(content) : null;
}
```

Now my question is, can this `if-else` clause be removed or make it more clear by using lambdas. I am new in lambdas and does not have very good idea on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether the code below even compiles due to the vagueness.

```
private ContentWrapper getContentWrapper(input1, input2, ....) {
    Optional<RenderedContent> content = some_condition
        ? service1
                .fetchTheCompletableFuture(..... inputs...)
                .join()
                .map(ListOutput::getList)
                .stream()
                .findFirst()
        : service2
                .fetchTheCompletableFuture(..... inputs...)
                .join();
    }
    return content
                .map(RenderedContent::getContent)
                .map(ContentWrapper::new).orElse(null);
}
```

- The first service seems to yield a list of RenderedContent of which to take the first if there is one.
- The second service may yield a Rendered content immediately.

So you can join the if-else to an `Optional<RenderedContent>`.
The `map(RenderedContent::getContent)` will yield `Optional.empty()` if it was empty to begin with. Otherwise `getContent` is called and wrapped in an `Optional`.
If present `new ContentWrapper(...)` might be called.

Notice much may fail, like getContent returning null (though there is an `Optional.ofNullable`.

Nevertheless Streams may be very expressive.

I would avoid using null in favor of `Optional` as that plays better together.